# Save a string to a h5py dataset using type "array of 8-bit integers (80)"

Tags: h5py

I wish to create a `h5py` "string" dataset (for example "A"), using the data type "array of 8-bit integers (80)" (as shown in HDFView, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhIZk.png)). Each integer of this array of length 80 is in fact `ord(x)` of the corresponding character of this string. So for instance `Top` is stored as `84 111 112 0 0 0 ...`, with in total 80 `int8`.

The desired dataset should look like this

```
DATASET "NOM" {
                     DATATYPE  H5T_ARRAY { [80] H5T_STD_I8LE }
                     DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
                     DATA {
                     (0): [ 84, 111, 112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
                     }
```

However I'm unable to create this dataset using `h5py`. Using a standard numpy array gives this

```
DATASET "NOM" {
                     DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I8LE
                     DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1, 80 ) / ( 1, 80 ) }
                     DATA {
                     (0,0): 84, 111, 112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     (0,15): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     (0,31): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     (0,47): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     (0,63): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     (0,79): 0
                     }
                  }
```

So what is `data` and `dtype` needed, if my string, say, is "Top".

```
.create_dataset("NOM", data=data, dtype=dtype)
```

According to https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/955, maybe I need to use a lower level interface...?

Thanks!

### Solution

The problem is that if we create the numpy dataset `data` before writing it by using `.create_dataset("NOM", data=data)`, internally numpy will always interpret my `80int8` data type as a 1d array of `int8`

```
dtype = np.dtype("80int8")
x = np.array(2, dtype=dtype)
# x.dtype = dtype('int8')
```

The solution is thus to declare the data set with the desired `dtype` first, then fill in the data.

```
dataset = gro.create_dataset("NOM", (len(nom),), dtype="80int8")
for i in range(len(nom)):
    nom_80 = nom[i] + "\x00" * (80 - len(nom[i]))  # make nom 80 characters
    dataset[i] = [ord(x) for x in nom_80]
# dataset.dtype = dtype(('i1', (80,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `uint8` array of right size and content:

```
In [417]: x = np.zeros(80, dtype='uint8')                                                 
In [419]: x[:3]=[ord(i) for i in 'Top']                                                                                                                                
In [421]: ds1=hf.create_dataset('other4', data=x)
```

---

A structured array approach:

```
In [486]: dt = np.dtype([('f0','80int8')])                                                
In [487]: dt                                                                              
Out[487]: dtype([('f0', 'i1', (80,))])
In [488]: x = np.zeros(1, dt)                                                             
In [489]: x['f0'][0][:3]=[ord(i) for i in 'Top']                                          
In [490]: x                                                                               
Out[490]: 
array([([ 84, 111, 112,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'i1', (80,))])
In [491]: ds1=hf.create_dataset('st1', data=x)                                            
In [492]: ds1                                                                             
Out[492]: <HDF5 dataset "st1": shape (1,), type "|V80">
```

produces

```
   DATASET "st1" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_ARRAY { [80] H5T_STD_I8LE } "f0";
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): {
            [ 84, 111, 112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However with this I got [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4027283/54773610-38552980-4c0a-11e9-88d7-90091f53698f.png), not exactly the same that I want (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhIZk.png)). Please forget the 2 here though.

Comment: You may need to define a `vlen` dtype.

Comment: The only external viewer that I have `h5dump`, so I can't say for sure what we produce is the same as what the OP expects or not.

Comment: I updated some details. The `DATATYPE` and `DATASPACE` are different.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj for your help, however there is no such field names in my dataset, and the `DATATYPE` is not `H5T_COMPOUND`...

Comment: Ok I solved the problem...I will update my question...Thank you for your time anyway!